# How can I create the test profiles in LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

Please assist
I can't find any documentation about how can I get or create test LinkedIn profiles for testing proposes

What I've found here  https://legal.linkedin.com/api-terms-of-use

it's only what I got

> 2.3   Test Profiles
>
> You may create up to five test LinkedIn profiles for purposes of
> testing your Application only. You must create the profiles manually
> and not via automated means, such as scripts.
>
> Test profiles must: (a) be standard LinkedIn member profiles; (b) not
> interact with non-test profiles (for example, you cannot use test
> accounts to comment on posts and you cannot connect test profiles with
> non-test profiles, such as your own personal LinkedIn profile); and
> (c) not override our API call limits.  You must clearly identify the
> profiles as test profiles, and you must identify these additional
> account profiles as “developers” in your Application registration. You
> may not create any profile positions at real companies (besides your
> own) for the test profiles.

Comment: It's right there in the passage you quoted. "*Test profiles must: (a) be standard LinkedIn member profiles .... You must clearly identify the profiles as test profiles*". So just make an account the normal way but call them Testy McTesterson or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it's not cool. 
I've been thinking to use those data for the sign up flow with integration with my app.
So, there is no opportunity to use real test users as like Facebook developers provide
Too sad (

Comment: LinkedIn's whole website is pretty janky considering their size. It doesn't surprise me that they don't have the resources to add features specifically for developers, when they don't have the resource to make the main website work properly.

Comment: It seems true )